# Uniquely identify disk

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

When I provisioned the Azure VM I explicitly gave a name for each disk based on what type SQL Server files/database it is going to be used for. Please see the image below.
[image]

However, Get-PhysicalDisk command output as
[image]

What I am trying to do is create Storage Pool based on the name I specified during VM creation i.e.  Create a storage pool called TempDB using _TempDBData_1 and _TempDBData2

Thanks

Comment: i don't have that cmdlet on win7ps5.1, but the DISPLAYED props a cmdlet shows are rarely ALL the props. have you tried sending the result to `Get-Member` to see all the props?

Comment: Something like `Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*_TempDBData_*"} | Select-Object Name,OperationalStatus,HealthStatus,Size,Usage` perhaps?

Comment: The Azure disk name will not display inside the VM. And you see all the things you can set for the disk [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2018-06-01/disks).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LUN to match the disk, however, when you provision the VM label disk correctly.

```
$filters=@("*datadisk*","*TempDB*","*LogDiskSystemDB*")
$azuredisk=((get-azvm  -ResourceGroupName "rsg" -Name "server").StorageProfile.DataDisks)|Where-Object {$_.Name -like  $filters[$i] }|Select-object -ExpandProperty "LUN"
```

on the server

```
$PhysicalDisks =(Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true )|Where-Object -Match PhysicalLocation "LUN [$azuredisk]"
```